# Spring Security authentication decision

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

In my Spring Security I have an issue. When I access url's like /admin, /client or even /admin/addUser.jsp it returns me to a login page (as it necessary) but when I access the url like /addUser (which mapped to Spring MVC controller) it returns me a page in any case even if user is not authenticated. What configuration I need to add/remove/modify in order to Security performs everything well.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

       <security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true"> <!--access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager"-->
            <security:intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll"/>
            <security:intercept-url pattern="/admin*/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
            <security:intercept-url pattern="/client*/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
            <security:form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/index" authentication-failure-url="/loginFail"
                                 authentication-success-handler-ref="redirectRoleStrategy"/>
            <security:logout logout-success-url="/logout" invalidate-session="true"/>
            <security:access-denied-handler error-page="/403"/>
       </security:http>

       <bean id="daoAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
           <property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService"/>
       </bean>

       <bean id="authenticationManager" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager">
            <property name="providers">
                <list>
                    <ref local="daoAuthenticationProvider"/>
                </list>
            </property>
       </bean>

        <security:authentication-manager>
            <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService"/>
        </security:authentication-manager>

        <bean id="redirectRoleStrategy" class="com.payment.system.util.RoleBasedAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
            <property name="roleUrlMap">
                <map>
                    <entry key="ROLE_ADMIN" value="/admin"/>
                    <entry key="ROLE_USER" value="/client"/>
                </map>
            </property>
        </bean>
</beans>
```

P.S.: By the way, my IDEA strikes-through me a `<property name="providers">` line reporting me that this property is deprecated. To what property I should replace this?

Thank you!

Comment: who should have access to `/addUser`

Comment: user with ROLE_ADMIN only

Answer (score 1):

Just add

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isFullyAuthenticated()" />
```

**after all** yours intercept-url tags (I mean it must be the last one)

For PS question: as explained in javadoc just use use constructor injection (via **constructor-arg** tag).

Answer (score 0):

When you will add the configuration suggested by Maksym it will solve your authentication problem. But it will NOT solve your authorization problem. A user with the role ROLE_USER will be able to access to /addUser.
Two solutions:

1) Move all URLs that should be accessed by admin under to /admin**. This solution may be complicated.

2) Replace configuration suggested my Maxim by the following configuration:

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
```

Please not that in this case the user with the role ROLE_USER will be able to access only to URLs /client*/**

Please tell me if you need any additional help.

Best regards,

```
Michael
```

P.S. I recommend to define all beans via namespace as explained here: http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/ns-config.html

It should eliminate warnings.

Comment: Thank you all for reply. I have reached needed functional. But what about PS in the end of my start post? :)